# I cant retrieve the value of $_COOKIE['mycookiename'] when request sent to server with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I want to send something to server with ajax `GET` method and also using cookies, so I send my value to ajax, I need this value to update the current cookie value. In ajax file, I can't retrieve `$_COOKIE['cookie_name']` , when I echo this, the result will be like this-->  []  !

```
function card(action,value) {
    if (value == "") {
        document.getElementById('errmsgs').innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('errmsgs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET","inc/pricing/pricing.php?act="+action+"&val="+value,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

And the pricing page is:

```
<?php 
require_once '../../connection.php';
require_once '../../func.php';

$what_is_action = $_REQUEST['act']; 
$myCook = $_REQUEST['val'];

}
echo $full_cookie_value = $_COOKIE['mycookiename']; ----> output will be--> [] ---->but it must be something like this ---> {"wwde34":"1","effy33":"1","ssdfff":"1"}


if($what_is_action == 'delete'){
    //delete_cook($myCook);
}
?>
```

---

Solved.
The problem was, when I trying to create the cookie, it was not in root, so in another folders It can't be accessible! so I added '/' at the last parameter of setcookie
for example: `setcookie('a','b',time()+36666,'/')`
this will create cookie in root and it can be accessible in other folders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Has your cookie been made?**

Make sure the cookie is set! Example: [image]

Where you see the I button you will need to press it and find the cookie and capsulses, check if you can find your cookie in there! This must be done from your website.

**Getting the error**

```
try
{
    echo $_COOKIE['name']['bills'];
}
catch (Throwable $t) // PHP 7
{
    echo '<b>COOKIE is not made</b>';
}
catch (Exception $e) // PHP 5
{
    echo '<b>COOKIE is not made</b>';
}
```

**Please have a look at** : [Getting cookies with javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: The I button is found at the left side with the link bar in google chrome

Comment: yes it has been made ,in another page ,and I write the value of current cookie here , {"wwde34":"1","effy33":"1","ssdfff":"1"} .

Comment: I can retreive the value in all of my pages ,but here ,in ajax php page ,It s not the true value !! it show me just two brackets ! I wonder about it :-D

Comment: Please try it out with javascript. Have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Is there any code that might have been manipulating your code?

Comment: not at all , I have a page that is named a.php ,in a.php  I call the ajax ,and also I echo my cookie for test,it returns the correct value .but in ajax ,the wrong result is shown !   ok i will check it out with javascript .thanks , but what s wrong with ajax ? :| :-(

Comment: Nothing is wrong with AJAX, but sometimes the script might be occured when using AJAX, it has happened to me before. So now I have gone over to just using Javascript when making cookies

Comment: clue_num=1473965507%2F%2F%2F1%2F%2F%2F1%2F%2F%2F1%2F%2F%2F1%2F%2F%2F1; null; clue=%7B%22wwde34%22%3A%221%22%2C%22effy33%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ssdfff%22%3A%221%22%7D; PHPSESSID=vhasnboi7urnijusk7kn6b3j85; clue=%7B%22wwde34%22%3A%221%22%2C%22effy33%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ssdfff%22%3A%221%22%2C%22w2343r%22%3A%221%22%7D

Comment: so how can I retrieve this value from it -> mycookie name is : clue and its value is :
{"wwde34":"1","effy33":"1","ssdfff":"1"}

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that, if that is the actual code from your file, that you're not assigning a variable after the echo, right?

`echo full_cookie_value` should be `echo $full_cookie_value`, or if you tried echoing 'full_cookie_value' as a "label", `echo 'full_cookie_value '.$_COOKIE['mycookiename']`

Comment: its ok ,this is a typing mistake that is taken here, It s just a sample code , I just echo out the value of $_COOKIE['something'],and it gave me the wrong value.